# What was the idea behind Logistic growth model?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-dynamics

The Malthus model is given by

$\frac{dP(t)}{dt}=rP(t)$, where $r$ is the growth rate. This model ignores the competition for resources among individuals. So, Verhulst came up with a model

$\frac{dP(t)}{dt}=rP(t) \left(1-\frac{P(t)}{K}  \right)$, where $K$ is the carrying capacity of environment. My question is:

how he derived this model or what was the idea behind this model ?

In Strogatz book "Non linear dynamics and chaos", they give the following explanation:

Because $\frac{\dot P(t)}{P(t)}$, the per capita growth rate should decrease for the large population. A mathematical convenient way to incorporate these ideas is to assume that per capita growth rate decreases linearly with $P(t)$, which leads to logistic equation. Was this the original idea of Verhulst behind Logistic growth model ?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but I'm not sure if you are looking for a historical account, or an explanation of the mathematics, which are nicely incorporated [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/ecology/population-growth-and-regulation/a/exponential-logistic-growth), except for a critical issue: in the KA post the differential equations are not solved.

Comment: @AntoniParellada Actually I am interested in the historical account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wikipedia page for Verhulst has [links to his original writings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Fran%C3%A7ois_Verhulst#Works). In the first paper from 1838, he basically only says (on [p. 115](https://books.google.com/books?id=8GsEAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA115)) that since the growth rate of the population decreases as the number of inhabitants increases, we can subtract an unknown function $\varphi(p)$ from the right-hand side of the differential equation,
$$
\frac{dp}{dt} = mp - \varphi(p)
,
$$
and that the simplest hypothesis that one can make about the form of this function is that
$$
\varphi(p) = n p^2
.
$$
(He also mentions some other possible forms, like $np^\alpha$ or $n \log p$.)

Comment: Thanks I got the English translated version of this work.

Comment: (+1) It is interesting to note how this "simplest hypothesis that one can make" as in the linked document by Verhulst comes together as $mp - np^2=(m-np)p$ with $m-np=r_\text{max}\frac{K- p}{K},$ with $K$ being the carrying capacity, and hence making the per capita rate $r$ linearly dependent on the population $p.$

Answer (score 1):

I think the most natural "intuition" for the logistic growth model is a combined proportion:

- $\frac{dP}{dt}$ is proportional to the population at time $t$: $\frac{dP}{dt} \sim P(t)$

$\bf{and}$

- $\frac{dP}{dt}$ is proportional to the remaining carrier capacity at time $t$: $\frac{dP}{dt} \sim (K-P(t))$

Combining these two proportions by multiplying leads to the logistic differential equation:

$$\frac{dP}{dt} \sim P(t)(K-P(t)) \Leftrightarrow \frac{dP}{dt} \sim P(t)\left(1-\frac{P(t)}{K}\right)$$

But I am not sure whether these were the thoughts of Verhulst.

Comment: You want to say that $\frac{dP}{dt} \sim P(K-P)$

Comment: @ManojKumar: Multiplying the two proportions you get exactly this. Then you take out $K$ as a factor and put it into the factor of proportion and obtain the logistic equation you cited in your text.

Comment: @ManojKumar : I added this part to my answer.